Connect to SF with external IDP (EntraID)
We have an external CIAM solution for customers. EntraId is our IDP. Customers login on a online webportal (Single Page Javascript app) through an oAuth2 flow. Now I want to use the token a user has to make SF API calls besides calls to other systems.
SF should use the info within this token to determine which community user belongs to it. And the access rights need to be respected when requesting info from SF.
How do we configure this flow? We don’t want to login to SF. Neither the user nor the API Management platform should have to login in SF itself, because we will supply a JWT with all required info. SF needs to be tied to EntraId somehow to map it’s community users to. Besides the regular internal user EntraID through SSO.
Is this flow supported at all?
Thanks!

use the token a user has to make SF API calls besides calls to other systems. - Token Exchange is your friend
